# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pip._vendor.six'

Tags: python, django

I am doing some example from the book called Django for professionals. I am at the part where you have to run the django server with `docker-compose` command. However, I got an error like this:

```
 raise ImproperlyConfigured("Error loading psycopg2 module: %s" % e)
```

I realised that I needed to download psycopg2 with pip3 but then I got this error:

```
from pip._vendor.six import iteritems
```

ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pip._vendor.six'

I don't understand why I received this error since I followed every step on the book carefully. I am using virtualenv as well so i decided to open a new terminal and downloaded it there. Download was a success however when I download it in virtual environment I get an error. What do you guys think is the problem and how can I solve it?

Comment: Does this solution help you: https://github.com/pypa/pipenv/issues/4804 ?

Comment: Hey thanks but it didn't. -@Boketto